# Geotiff in leaflet

Tags: leaflet, tiff

I am creating a webmap using leaflet and I need to display tif raster images. I consulted all the types of methods to display these data; however, I do not understand so much, so I am having some difficulties.
I already tried to install the leaflet-geotiff from github, but I was not able to use it. I also try the georaster-layer-for-leaflet and also I was not able to use it.

Can anyone help me please?
Thank you